# Good ways to sort a queryset? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

what I'm trying to do is this:

- get the 30 Authors with highest score ( `Author.objects.order_by('-score')[:30]` )
- order the authors by `last_name`

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: @RH: so how about checking AlexMartelli's answer as the correct solution? (not that he needs any more rep, unless he's going after that Skeet guy...)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

What about

```
import operator

auths = Author.objects.order_by('-score')[:30]
ordered = sorted(auths, key=operator.attrgetter('last_name'))
```

In Django 1.4 and newer you can order by providing multiple fields.
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

**order_by(*fields)**

By default, results returned by a `QuerySet` are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the `ordering` option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the `order_by` method.

**Example:**

```
ordered_authors = Author.objects.order_by('-score', 'last_name')[:30]
```

The result above will be ordered by `score` descending, then by `last_name` ascending. The negative sign in front of `"-score"` indicates descending order. Ascending order is implied.

Comment: @Alex: grazie alex! That was great, I'm off to read about the operator module!

Comment: Is this more efficient than Author.objects.order_by('-score', 'last_name')[:30]?

Comment: @Brian - if by "more efficient" you mean "more correct" then yes, its. :) Your solution keeps the authors pretty much sorted by score, and only alphabetizes those authors with the same score (which is how secondary keys work). Alex shows how to take the results, and then apply a completely different sort order to them (using key=operator.attrgetter to define a per-object key expression), which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Paul: that's not what I asked though, Alex's answer is the correct one!

Comment: @RH: Sorry for my obtuseness of expression - I was trying to say the same thing, that Alex's posted solution, as usual, is the correct one. @jathanism nicely walks through why using multiple args to order_by gives a result that does not match your original request.

Comment: From my understanding, order_by(x, y, z) sorts result by x first, then takes the result and sorts the items with the same x by y, then takes that result and sorts the items with the same y by z. Sort is done by the DB and Django returns a lazy result. Doing it in Python will(?) fetch 'last_name' from the db for all items before doing the sort. Paul, I see where you are going with this, as I am having hard time NOT translating the question to one that can be solved by order_by.

Comment: Why not making the sorting key function `lambda x: x.last_name`? It's shorter, more verbose and doesn't need any import.

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Comment: What is [:30] at the end?

Comment: @E.Praneeth the [:30] is limiting the results to the 30 objects in the query, in this case the 30 highest scores.

Comment: It's a good solution. But as it comes to sort the qs by object's foreign key's field. The lambda function can't work on it. :;(

Answer (score 18):

I just wanted to illustrate that the built-in solutions (SQL-only) are not always the best ones.  At first I thought that because Django's `QuerySet.objects.order_by` method accepts multiple arguments, you could easily chain them:

```
ordered_authors = Author.objects.order_by('-score', 'last_name')[:30]
```

But, it does not work as you would expect.  Case in point, first is a list of presidents sorted by score (selecting top 5 for easier reading):

```
>>> auths = Author.objects.order_by('-score')[:5]
>>> for x in auths: print x
... 
James Monroe (487)
Ulysses Simpson (474)
Harry Truman (471)
Benjamin Harrison (467)
Gerald Rudolph (464)
```

Using Alex Martelli's solution which accurately provides the top 5 people sorted by `last_name`:

```
>>> for x in sorted(auths, key=operator.attrgetter('last_name')): print x
... 
Benjamin Harrison (467)
James Monroe (487)
Gerald Rudolph (464)
Ulysses Simpson (474)
Harry Truman (471)
```

And now the combined `order_by` call:

```
>>> myauths = Author.objects.order_by('-score', 'last_name')[:5]
>>> for x in myauths: print x
... 
James Monroe (487)
Ulysses Simpson (474)
Harry Truman (471)
Benjamin Harrison (467)
Gerald Rudolph (464)
```

As you can see it is the same result as the first one, meaning it doesn't work as you would expect.

Comment: Your result #3 is sorting descending by score and then by last_name IFF any objects have the same score.  The problem is none of the objects in your result set have the same score so only the '-score' is affecting the sort order.  Try setting 3 authors score to 487 and run #3 again.

Comment: Yeah I understand that.  I really just wanted to illustrate that the built-in solutions (SQL-only) are not always the best ones.

Comment: It did exactly what I expected: lexicographic ordering (which is kinda' trivial if the first sorting key is all distinct).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way that allows for ties for the cut-off score.

```
author_count = Author.objects.count()
cut_off_score = Author.objects.order_by('-score').values_list('score')[min(30, author_count)]
top_authors = Author.objects.filter(score__gte=cut_off_score).order_by('last_name')
```

You may get more than 30 authors in top_authors this way and the `min(30,author_count)` is there incase you have fewer than 30 authors.