# Django custom order_by

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by

I've got a model eg. Car with a foreign key eg. Owner, which may or may not be blank.
The Car has a creation_date.

I would like to order these cars by date, but if the car has an owner, the date of birth of the owner must be taken instead of the creation_date of the car.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this similar question: [Good ways to sort a queryset? - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412770/good-ways-to-sort-a-queryset-django)

You can't use the model's Meta `ordering` as it only accepts one field

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

You can't use the query `order_by('creation_date', 'birthdate')` as it only sorts by birthdate if they have the same `creation_date`

So, you could write a custom manager to do incorporate a custom sort for you.

```
import operator
class CarManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        auths = super(CarManager, self).get_query_set().all().order_by('-creation')
        ordered = sorted(auths, key=operator.attrgetter('birthday'))
        return ordered

class Car(models.Model):
    sorted = CarManager()
```

so now you can query:

```
Car.sorted.all()
```

to get all a queryset of sorted car's

Comment: I used this and it worked! I defined a function in my custom manager where I converted the queryset to a list with list(), and then did an insertion sort with car.date as key. get_date is a method in my Car model that returns the birthdate of the owner or the creation date of the car. I later defined car.date as property(get_date). Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to be cateful with `list()`: `list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it. Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory. In contrast, iterating over a QuerySet will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate objects only as you need them.` [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Answer (score 6):

This is possible by falling back to SQL:

```
Car.objects.filter(...).extra(select={'odate': '''
  if(owner_id,
     (select date_of_birth from owner_table where id=owner_id),
     creation_date
  )
'''}).order_by('odate')
```

`if` function is MySQL-specific.  In case of SQLite or Postgres you should use `case` statement.

Comment: Django is designed to be database independent, so I prefer Timmy's solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method that returns the appropriate date (if car has owner return birthday else return creation_date) and then [order your model based on this method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/django-queryset-order-by-method)

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution. But the example you give is annotation of the sum, an aggregate function. I want to annotate it with my own function.