# Creating a custom order_by or sort in django

Tags: python, django

What would be the pragmatic way to create a custom order_by or sort function in python/Django, I'm not sure if you could just override the order by function. Ideally it would sort the passed on object/items according to an algorithm?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to your needs? An `order_by` is pretty flexible.

Comment: This seems similar...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619554/django-custom-order-by

Comment: i was kind of thinking that I'd sort the queryset by a custom method based on a specific sorting algorithm. like a bubble sort or something similar?

Comment: You can't, `order_by` is just an interface for SQL ordering. You should convert queryset to list and sort that list in Python (it will be very slow and resource-consuming on big datasets though).