# Django order_by on charfield with alphanumeric characters and foreign key lookup

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a situation where I need to pass through an ordered table to my template, trouble is the table has some rows which are numeric, others which are text and others that are a combination of both. The first column on which the table is sorted has a foreign key relationship.

This is my query at the moment:

```
placing = ClubPlacing.objects.filter(event=event).order_by('division__code','placing')
```

Both `division__code` and `placing` have rows which are numeric and text. (in models as a charfield)

When the data is displayed I have `1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5... ...CT, O1` (that last one is the letter `O`)

The placing column displays `1, 10, 11, 2, 3... ...no comp`

I am using Django 1.8 and Postgres on Linux.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535451/natural-sort-on-django-queryset

Comment: Thanks Paulo, looks a bit complicated to setup, will test it thanks.