# Order object by field containing string value

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a django model and a field representing an ip-address. I want order queryset of this model by ip-address value such `"10.10.10.1"`

I do `Model.objects.order_by("ip_address")`, but I get this

`QuerySet["10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.11", "10.10.10.12", ...]`

I want this `QuerySet["10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.2", "10.10.10.3", ...]`

I don't know how to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Postgresql has [data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html) to represent network addresses. Using the `inet` to for your column would yield the ordering you want (plus some useful [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)). If changing the column's type is possible that would be my first recommandation.

Comment: See this post about custom order by in django - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619554/django-custom-order-by

Comment: @Marth i found field `GenericIPAddressField` in django models. I think it will be helpful for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @TomRon it is useful to me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I did it:

```
class IPAddressManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().extra(
            select={'ordered_ip_addresses': "string_to_array(ip_address, '.')::int[]", },
        )

    def all_ordered_objects(self):
        return self.order_by("ordered_ip_addresses")


class IPAddress(models.Model):

    objects = IPAddressManager()
    ip_address = models.CharField()
```

now when we will call `IPAddress.objects.all_ordered_objects()` we will have really ordered set