# Django admin: sorting/ordering dynamic readonly_fields

Tags: django, sorting, admin

how can I sort/order readonly_fields (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)?

here is what I do:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('pinCount')
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'pinCount')

    def pinCount(self, instance):
        return Pin.objects.filter(user=instance).count()

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

In the admin it should be possible to sort the list by pinCount. Since it's not a direct database field, that's not possible according to the docs. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ordering is done by the DB, not by the admin (this is debug toolbar output on a change list):

[image]

that's why you can't order by using a custom admin method. You could add a `Count` annotation to the admin's queryset by overwriting the [`ModeAdmin.queryset` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs \
            .annotate(pin_count=Count('pin')) \
            .order_by('-pin_count')
```

or if you need more control, you could try [sort the queryset displayed by the admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412770/good-ways-to-sort-a-queryset-django) but I haven't tested this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def pin_count(self):
        return self.pin.count()


import operator  
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return sorted(qs, key=operator.attrgetter('pin_count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but there seem to be solutions (one that involes defining a custom ModelManager for the model in question, and another one that relies on admin interface magic):
[Django admin: how to sort by one of the custom list_display fields that has no database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d)

The problem in your case is that the model in question is the User model, which is probably not a good idea to change. In your case, I'd suggest for adding a custom UserProfile model, as described here:
[Django user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile)

If you need to query by this value frequently, I'd suggest to materialize the pinCount value for each user in your user profile model. Depending on your requirements you could use a database trigger to keep this value updated.