# what is the traditional way of sorting search results?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am stuck in this issue since yesterday.

i have a page which i am writing in django/python. and i have a search function in project. one searches and comes to result page. HERE is the issue:

which possibilities are there to implement the sort tool? what i know are:

1. with Jquery's `load()` function, i load the part of the page where results are
2. i heard of dajaxice which does the similiar job

this is all what i know. now i am fighting with `load` and having difficulties. is there any other technologies in django to make `sort the results`?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the results"? Sort alphabetically? Or by what specs?

Comment: @HieuNguyen, there can be any specs like date,alphabet,rate and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort it in Django using the instructions found here: [Good ways to sort a queryset? - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412770/good-ways-to-sort-a-queryset-django).

Instead of using jQuery, I'd recommend that you use [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#sortBy) to sort your array.

It depends on where you'd like to sort your array and which framework you're more comfortable with, although I would lean towards the Django solution as it allows you to avoid an import.

Comment: thanks. i dont use arrays, i am rendering querysets to template.

Comment: @dan-klasson. yes, :)