# Best way to have order_by and distinct different columns in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-database

I'm trying to do the following with a PostgreSQL DB:

```
team_updates = TeamUpdate.objects.filter(team__in = TeamStarred.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('team'))
team_updates = team_updates.order_by('-date','team__name').distinct('team__name')
```

This would technically solve the problem, but it causes the ordering to now be by team_name rather than date.

```
team_updates = TeamUpdate.objects.filter(team__in = TeamStarred.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('team'))
team_updates = team_updates.order_by('team__name', '-date').distinct('team__name')
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412770/good-ways-to-sort-a-queryset-django ?

Comment: Yes, that question/answer doesn't speak to the issue with having a field be distinct