# How to select only one row for one user in django?

Tags: django, sqlite, filter

I have a message database and it has senderid, receiverid, message and date. Now I would like to get list of users whom I have recently messaged with one latest message (sent or received) per person. How can I get just a single row of message per person.

I tried but this game me all the messages between two users, I just want the latest message.

```
querySet=MessageModel.objects.filter(
            Q(sUser=self.request.user) |     
            Q(rUser=self.request.user)
        )
        return querySet
```

but this game me all the messages between two users, I just want the latest message.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the QuerySet and then just grab the first item in the list.

```
querySet = MessageModel.objects.filter(
    Q(sUser=self.request.user) |     
    Q(rUser=self.request.user)
).order_by('-date')[0]
```

`.order_by(...)` sorts a QuerySet based on a specific field (ascending order is implied). By using `.order_by('-date')`, the `-date` denotes we want a descending order, rather than the default ascending order. We can then just grab the first item in our QuerySet with `[0]`.

Further reading: [Good ways to sort a queryset? - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412770/good-ways-to-sort-a-queryset-django)